# "Training must be numeric" error while using fitNaiveBayes in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am using the [Spambase dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Spambase) from the Machine Learning UCI Repository for Naive Bayes classification using the function `fitNaiveBayes` in matlab. However, it is giving me the error:

```
Error using NaiveBayes.fit (line 11)
TRAINING must be numeric.

Error in fitNaiveBayes (line 120)
model = NaiveBayes.fit(training, group,varargin{:});

Error in Q1NaiveBayes (line 22)
Mdl = fitNaiveBayes(x_tr,y_tr);
```

Could anyone please help me understand what could be going wrong? The dataset seems to be numeric (even though it does have quite a large frequency of zero values)

Comment: What is the exact function you're calling? What are you passing in? I'd first check everything you're passing in is of class double. eg. `class(training)` etc... returns double. It sounds like something isn't of class double that's supposed to be.

Comment: @MatthewGunn Thanks to your comment I just realized I was passing a table! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your data set must be numeric Such as UCI heart disease data set.
[See here (UCI heart disease data set)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCzx4.png)